# Cannot find module '@expo/metro-config' when i run "npx react-native start

Tags: node.js, react-native

I'm trying to run the command "npx react-native start" and shows this error

```
error Cannot find module '@expo/metro-config'
Require stack:
- D:\Projetos\apporto\metro.config.js
- D:\Projetos\apporto\node_modules\cosmiconfig\node_modules\import-fresh\index.js
- D:\Projetos\apporto\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\loaders.js
- D:\Projetos\apporto\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\createExplorer.js
- D:\Projetos\apporto\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\index.js
- D:\Projetos\apporto\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\readConfigFromDisk.js
- D:\Projetos\apporto\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\index.js
- D:\Projetos\apporto\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\install\install.js
- D:\Projetos\apporto\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\index.js
- D:\Projetos\apporto\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js
- D:\Projetos\apporto\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js
Error: Cannot find module '@expo/metro-config'
Require stack:
- D:\Projetos\apporto\metro.config.js
- D:\Projetos\apporto\node_modules\cosmiconfig\node_modules\import-fresh\index.js
- D:\Projetos\apporto\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\loaders.js
- D:\Projetos\apporto\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\createExplorer.js
- D:\Projetos\apporto\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\index.js
- D:\Projetos\apporto\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\readConfigFromDisk.js
- D:\Projetos\apporto\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\index.js
- D:\Projetos\apporto\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\install\install.js
- D:\Projetos\apporto\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\index.js
- D:\Projetos\apporto\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js
- D:\Projetos\apporto\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:924:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projetos\apporto\metro.config.js:1:30)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)
```

I try to use the `npm i metro-config --save-dev` but doesn't work.

I don't know what to do.

package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "apporto",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-svg": "*",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-config": "^0.64.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: please post your `package.json` file contents

Comment: why don't you just edit the question and add it there?

Comment: @CornelRaiu sorry, it's my first time using here.

Answer (score 17):

After installing expo/metro-config:

```
npm i @expo/metro-config
```

Go to **metro.config.js** change:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');
```

To:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('@expo/metro-config');
```

It works for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The expo config file has been missing from here.
Run

```
npm i @expo/metro-config
```

In the main folder update the

> **metro.config.js**

Change the following line

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');
```

to

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('@expo/metro-config');
```

Works like a Charm!

Answer (score 3):

in upgrading from SDk 48 to SDK 49, to resolve the issue

> "Error: Cannot find module '@expo/metro-config'
> Require stack:"

just run this command `npx expo customize metro.config.js`
like this in the doc [customizing-metro](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/customizing-metro/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I downloaded expo metro config and that fixed the issue

```
npm i @expo/metro-config
```

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue when updating Expo SDK 48 to 49, and had used Expo Router at beta stage in 48. I tried different approaches but what worked was:

1. Rename existing metro.config.js to something else.
2. Run `npm i @expo/config`
3. Merge old metro-config with the newly generated

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstall `@expo/config` by typing this command into console.

```
npm i @expo/config
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score -2):

{
"name": "metro-config",
"version": "0.64.0",
"description": " Config parser for Metro.",
"main": "src/index.js",
"repository": {
"type": "git",
"url": "git@github.com:facebook/metro.git"
},
"scripts": {
"prepare-release": "test -d build && rm -rf src.real && mv src src.real && mv build src",
"cleanup-release": "test ! -e build && mv src build && mv src.real src"
},
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
"cosmiconfig": "^5.0.5",
"jest-validate": "^26.5.2",
"metro": "0.64.0",
"metro-cache": "0.64.0",
"metro-core": "0.64.0",
"metro-runtime": "0.64.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"pretty-format": "^26.5.2",
"strip-ansi": "^6.0.0"
}
}