# How to resolve 10%Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported with react native web?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native web app. And after I do expo start. I choose for w-web. But then I get this error:

```
] 10%Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
```

I am using node.js version  `v20.10.0.`

And my package.json file looks like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start, react-app-rewired start --openssl-legacy-provider ",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js",
    "postinstall": "patch-package",
    "build": "SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts build",
    "start-webpack": "webpack-dev-server --mode production --open"
  },
```

Question: how to resolve the error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Comment: It caused by version incompatibility between node.js and OpenSSL that posted [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/error-error-0308010c-digital-envelope-routines-unsupported-node-error-solved/) and [here](https://codeless.co/error-0308010c-digital-envelope-routines-unsupported/). And one way to solve it is using a flag called ```--openssl-legacy-provider``` that can setup in **package.json** so it become looks like this ```"scripts": {"start": "expo start --openssl-legacy-provider",...}```.

Comment: I have it now like "start": "expo start --openssl-legacy-provider, react-app-rewired start", but then I get this error:  Error: Cannot find module 'expo/config'

Comment: It's missing. Make sure ```expo``` already installed in project or do install it by running ```npm install expo``` or ```yarn add expo```. If done already and still error check the module reference. You should use ```require('@expo/config')``` not ```require('expo/config')```. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67115652/cannot-find-module-expo-metro-config-when-i-run-npx-react-native-start) if needed.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about the changes you made when switching from yarn to npm? Did you update any other dependencies or configurations during this process?

Comment: @Keyboard Corporation.
   Oke, I found the file: AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\webpack-config\webpack\env. And I changed. Thx. Everything works fine now. I can mark your answare as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error caused by version incompatibility between node.js and OpenSSL. And one way to solve it is using a flag called `--openssl-legacy-provider` that can setup in **package.json**.

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "expo start --openssl-legacy-provider",
   ...
}
```

If encountering error like;

**Error: Cannot find module 'expo/config'**

Make sure `expo` already installed in project by running `npm install expo` or `yarn add expo`.

If done already and still error check the module reference. You should use `require('@expo/config')` not <strike>require('expo/config')</strike>. You can find the file at *"AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\webpack-config\webpack\env"* (like on this case).